# Function that is intended to return an array is returning undefined. Console.log(array) within function returns the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am trying to write a function that takes an array and returns a new array with all elements shifted n indices to the left. For example:

```
rotLeft([1,2,3,4],2)
// should return [3,4,1,2]
```

I wrote a recursive function that removes the value at index 0 and assigns it to last index using .shift() and .push().

```
const rotLeft = (array, n) => {
  console.log(array, n); // <-- this prints out expected array
  if (!n) return array; // <-- but this returns undefined! :(
  array.push(array.shift());
  rotLeft(array, n - 1);
};
console.log(rotLeft([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 9));
```

How come each console.log(array) prints out the expected array but the array is undefined when the function returns?

Comment: You need to return the result of recursion: `return rotLeft(array, n - 1);`

Comment: because you don't return the value you get from recursion

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the rotated array (for each recursive call), you need another `return` for `rotLeft(array, n - 1)`:

```js
const rotLeft = (array, n) => {
  // console.log(array, n);
  if (!n) return array;
  array.push(array.shift());
  return rotLeft(array, n - 1); // <-- return the rotated array (recursively)
};
console.log(...rotLeft([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 2));
```

Even shorter (with `concat` and the ternary operator):

```js
const rotLeft = (array, n) => {
  return n ? rotLeft(array.concat([array.shift()]), n - 1) : array;
};
console.log(...rotLeft([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below. You are not returning the results from function. I just added the return statement

```
const rotLeft = (array, n) => {
  //console.log(array, n); // <-- this prints out expected array
  if (!n) return array; // <-- but this returns undefined! :(
  array.push(array.shift());
  return rotLeft(array, n - 1);
};
```

**Usage:**
rotLeft([1,2,3,4],2)

**Output**
[image]

Comment: No problem :-) it happens thats why we have this online community to help each other. Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return` the recursive call.

```js
const rotLeft = (array, n) => {
  if (!n) return array;
  array.push(array.shift());
  return rotLeft(array, n - 1);
};
console.log(rotLeft([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 9));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to archive this

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4]

const rotLeft = (arr, n) => arr.slice(n).concat(arr.slice(0,n))

const tmp1 = rotLeft(arr, 2)
const tmp2 = rotLeft(arr, 3)
console.log("tmp1", tmp1)
console.log("tmp2", tmp2)
```